# Unable to show a different value after detecting an undefined variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the script below to detect city and state from geo.js, but sometimes city comes back as 'undefined' because city is not returned in the array response. How can I detect if json.city is undefined and show something else in "citybody" if city is not detected?

```html
<script async src="https://get.geojs.io/v1/ip/geo.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">

        function geoip(json){
        var userip      = json.ip;
    var city      = json.city;
    var region      = json.region;
    
    console.log (json.city);
    console.log (json.region);
    console.log (json.ip);
    

    document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = json.city ;
    document.getElementById("region").innerHTML = json.region ;
    document.getElementById("citybody").innerHTML = json.city ;
    document.getElementById("regionbody").innerHTML = json.region ;
    document.getElementById("region3").innerHTML = json.region ;
 }   
</script>
```

I've tried using json.city != 'undefined' but does not work.

Comment: `json.city || 'Unkown city'`

Comment: `json.city != null` will check to see that the property is neither null nor undefined. You could also (as mentioned in the other comment) just test `json.city` as if it were a boolean value, which will also tell you if it's non-null but it's an empty string.

Comment: city isn't even being returned though so i can't check to see if the values are valid. Example response returned:   geoip({"country":"United States","country_code":"US","country_code3":"USA","continent_code":"NA","region":"Rhode Island","accuracy":100,"area_code":"0","timezone":"America\/New_York"})

Comment: Note that `null` and `undefined` should **not** be in quotes; that is, not `"undefined"`, because that's a non-empty string and not the value `undefined`.